# How to display youtube video on website using GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, iframe, youtube

I am trying to include a youtube video on website that I'm developing using GAE and python.

I know I should use this`<iframe width="420" height="345"
src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MYSVMgRr6pw">
</iframe>` in my HTML, but I am also guessing I have to make some changes in app.yaml file. I can't figure out how to amend my app.yaml correctly. Currently I can only see a square box and no video. Here is a link to a web page with a video http://www.firstpiproject.appspot.com/learninglinux

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, per http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_youtube.asp, that the canonical form is something like, and I quote:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315"
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k">
</iframe>
```

Note the slightly different format for the `src=` URL, with `.../embed/` -- your page has `src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBvaB8aAp1I&feature=youtu.be"`, which is a somewhat-different format.

I don't think this has anything to do with App Engine, python, `app.yaml`, and the like -- it's all about what, exactly, you put in that `src=` parameter of the `iframe` you serve as part of your HTML page.  Try the w3schools-recommended format with `.../embed/...` and let us know!

Comment: This exactly what I did and it didn't work. You should be able to see that on web page source, at the link that I provided

Comment: @serine, I did "view source" on that page -- that's where i copied and pasted the `/watch?' `src=` from!  What `src=` do *you* see when you "view source" for that same page?!

Comment: This is what I see when I "view source" `<iframe width="420" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBvaB8aAp1I&feature=youtu.be">
</iframe>` lines 49-50. I tried `<embed >` , still no video, but now it says plugin is missing. You can see for your self. Here is the video I trying to add (www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBvaB8aAp1I&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: You're not reading what Alex is saying. You are using the wrong URL.

Comment: @serine, now you're using an `<embed>` **tag**, which is completely different.  Go back to using the `<iframe>` tag, as you originally had and as my answer also recommends, and instead just change the **URL** in the `src=` attribute of that tag to be `youtube.com/embed/hBvaB8aAp1I` instead of `youtube,com/watch?v=hBvaB8aAp1I` which you originally used, did not work, and, as Greg points out, is wrong.

Comment: @Alex Martelli, thanks for being patient. I didn't read the answer properly. All sorted now. Cheers